# C# Как получить значение переменной С в основном потоке?

Tags: c#

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Thread myThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(count));
    myThread.Start();
    Console.WriteLine(C); // Как получить значение переменной С в основном потоке?
    Console.ReadLine();
}
static void count()
{
    int A = 1;
    int B = 2;
    int C = A + B;
}
```

Comment: Пример слишком простой, тут вам просто можно поток не создавать, а вернуть значение из функции. А в варианте с потоком будет зависеть от многих факторов - сколько значений вы хотите вернуть, когда вы их хотите вернуть, как часто вы их возвращаете и т.д.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var c = 0;
    var thread = new Thread(() => { c = Count(); });
    thread.Start();
    thread.Join();
    Console.WriteLine(c.ToString());
    Console.ReadLine();
}

public int Count()
{
    int A = 1;
    int B = 2;
    return A + B;
}
```